# Groovy Class Loader Problem

Tags: groovy

I am using both groovy and java within the eclipse environment to develop a UI application. I want to use groovy class loader within my code, So I've used the conventional way of getting hold of Groovy Class loader this way:

```
def str = new File("C:/myGroovyFile.groovy").getText()
def myclass = getClass();
println myclass //facing issue here
ClassLoader parent = myclass.getClassLoader();
GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(str);
```

Here the problem I am facing is that the getClass() when invoked in the eclipse environment is not returning the GroovyCOnsole script rather it is returning the java.lang.class on which getClassLoader() when invoked returns a null.

I want to get hold of groovy console script for getClass() which in turn can be useful to dynamically load my groovy file located at C:\

Please tell me how can I solve this issue.

PS: I am trying to place this code within a method called initialize(). As long as this code is within the main class, it works but when I enclose the above code within a custom user defined function it doesn't work. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Class+Loading
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Influencing+class+loading+at+runtime
http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html

Since you are able to get correct class loader from main, can you not pass the loader reference to initialize() as a method param?

I confronted a similar issue with Groovlets, where class loader appears to differ depending on context in which it is called (i.e. script or class scope).  Solution for me was to take script scope class loader and pass the loader ref to class scoped application.

Groovy user list has covered the topic of class loading in groovy at various times; obviously a great resource for all things Groovy ;--)
http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot! As of now I've passed the reference to the custom method but I was actually keen to know the reason why I cannot do the class loading in a separate method. This question is aimed to get an answer for the same :)

Comment: If you have not already done so, either check the four links in my edit above, or post to the Groovy user list where Jochen, Guillaume (core developers of Groovy itself) or other Groovy "heavy" will have an answer for you: