# Groovy rootLoader Issue

Tags: groovy, classpath

We have a project where we are not able to use the class path (-cp) argument on the command line.  We decided to use rootLoader to load necessary classes at run time.  However, we have encountered a problem using rootLoader to load a class at runtime.  Below are two simple examples.  The first one works, but the second one does not work.  Of course, the second example is the one that I need to work.  Both examples were run with a cmd file.

**working example**

```
println this.class.name
println new File("W:/JavaApps/lib/TWS_Test.jar").exists()
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL("file:///W:/JavaApps/lib/TWS_Test.jar"))
def simpleJar = Class.forName("Simple_Jar").newInstance();
simpleJar.printGreeting()
println simpleJar.returnGreeting()
println "Hello, TWS!"
```

**This is the output from above.**

```
HelloTWS_LC
true
Java-printGreeting
Java-returnGreeting
Hello, TWS!
"finish HelloTWS.groovy for High Volume Letters - rc 0"
```

**In this example, which explicitly defines the class and main method, rootLoader returns null**

```
class HelloTWS_LC {
   static void main(def args) {
      println this.class.name
      println new File("W:/JavaApps/lib/TWS_Test.jar").exists()
      this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL("file:///W:/JavaApps/lib/TWS_Test.jar"))
      def simpleJar = Class.forName("Simple_Jar").newInstance();
      simpleJar.printGreeting()
      println simpleJar.returnGreeting()
      println "Hello, TWS!"
   }
}
```

**Output from the non-working example.**

```
java.lang.Class
true
"finish HelloTWS.groovy for High Volume Letters - rc 1"
```

**There is an error in the cmd window.**

```
W:\JavaApps\DMCGroovyScripts>groovy  W:\JavaApps\DMCGroovyScripts\HelloTWS_LC.groovy  1>W:\JavaApps\DMCGroovyScripts\HelloTWS.txt
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'rootLoader' on null object java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'rootLoader' on null object
        at HelloTWS_LC.main(HelloTWS_LC.groovy:5)
```

Comment: Why can't you use the classpath parameter?

Comment: @Voy3966 was my answer useful? Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `rootLoader` that is *null* but `getClassLoader` method returns *null*.

The code below works find (prints `rootLoader`):

```
public class Lol {
    static void main(args) {
        println Lol.class.classLoader.rootLoader
    }
}
```

This example doesn't work (NPE):

```
public class Lol {
    static void main(args) {
        println getClass().classLoader.rootLoader
    }
}
```

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096544/groovy-class-loader-problem) question will be also useful.

Comment: @Voy3966, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: As an additional explanation: The second example is using a static method. `this` in a static method refers to the class. this.getClass(), is thus always java.lang.Class, which most of the time has null as loader, since that is the system loader, which loaded that class.